# FPGA temporal partitioning

Tags: fpga

Okay, I have very large designs to implement on FPGAs and heard about this concept of temporal partitioning that allows us to implement designs which swap in and out parts of the designs Although I couldn't find anything more than some research journal publications, some googling for temporal partitioning does show links for dynamic reconfigurable FPGAs.

So, what exactly are temporal partitioning and reconfigurable FPGAs? And are they useful in my application?

Comment: "Are they useful in your application?" - how is anyone supposed to know that without knowing your application?

Comment: Are you talking about from an academic point of view? Because yes you could possibly do that. Is it implemented by your FPGA manufacturer? NO. And you didn't even tell us the manufacturer of the FPGA which is critical. What advantage does this give you, are you worried about compile time? Please write well documented questions that are specific. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @laptop2d I'm sorry about this. I thought I had provided enough information but I see that perhaps I was wrong. While I haven't selected any manufacturer yet, I am partial towards Xilinx since my entire workflow revolves around ISE and Vivado. I am in academic research and use FPGAs for hardware acceleration of mathematical models. But, my research now needs dynamic reconfiguration to allow for my systems to swap out models on the fly. I hope that this is enough information for you to provide me with some insight.

Comment: I remember reading something about a lattice FPGA programming interface being reverse engineered, so if your up to rolling your own programmer, you might use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these things exist in the wild, but they are nontrivial to use.

The easiest case is full reconfiguration. The configuration memory stores multiple different variants, and you use the on-chip reset logic to restart the chip and load a different programming file. All internal state is lost, and the chip goes into the reset condition for a brief time.

If you can live with that, this is fairly easy to implement -- all you need is a larger configuration flash, and an instance of the dynamic reconfiguration hard IP block -- you tell it which image to load, and give a start signal, and you are done.

Proper partial reconfiguration also exists in mid- to high end FPGAs, here you can create partitions before compiling your design, and the fitter will respect partition boundaries, so you can load individual partitions' contents independently.

That is generally only available with an appropriate license, and not entirely easy to use, but it allows a partition that is not being reconfigured to continue running while another is reloaded.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Simon. As I was explaining to @laptop2d in the comments above, I'm in academic research and my work needs dynamic reconfiguration to allow for my systems to swap out models on the fly while the rest of the system continues regular operation. So, it would seem my requirement can't have a device-wide reset, unfortunately. Are there any devices you would recommend? In general, I'm partial towards Xilinx since my current workflow revolves around ISE and Vivado. But I'm open to jumping ship to Altera if what they offer is really good/satisfies my requirement.

Comment: @solaremperor, both Xilinx and Altera offer partial dynamic reconfiguration, but you need the appropriate license (neither includes this in the free license, not sure if the standard license already covers it, or if you need a special option).

Comment: @solaremperor, thinking about it: you might get away a lot cheaper by simply using two FPGAs, one containing the part that keeps running, and the other being reconfigured. This also allows you to have the first FPGA reconfigure the second through JTAG.